# TypeError: Cannot set property 'user' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, session

I am trying to get the express-session module working for my web app. I have seen many examples where people are getting the same errors, but the fixes that have been suggested continue to throw the same error.

Below is my login function where a session is created:

```
function login(user, req, res) {
    var query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email_address = ?";
    connection.query(query, user.lEmail, function (rows) {
        if (rows && rows.length) {
            bcrypt.compare(user.lPassword, rows[0].password, function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    req.session.user = rows[0]
                    console.log(session);
                    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/views/home.html"));
                } else {
                    console.log("Incorrect password");
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log("Incorrect Email Address");
        }
    });
    return query;
}
```

At the top of my file I have

```
var session = require("express-session");
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session({
    name: 'app.sid',
    secret: "1234567890QWERTY",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

as well as other modules such as express.

When I do `console.log(rows)`

I get the result:

```
RowDataPacket {
  user_id: 3,
  username: 'bob',
  password: '$2b$10$94/HBES88WxiTLCCR3IND.rNBO2SOrrY.kf2un2EFvRekr0LBJPbu',
  first_name: 'bob',
  last_name: 'ross',
  email_address: 'email@email.com',
  user_type: 0,
  date_created: 2021-09-02T12:00:00.000Z,
  date_modified: 2021-09-02T12:00:00.000Z
}
```

I did some other tests trying to set something like session.user = rows[0].user_id but it throws the error even though rows[0].user_id in this case would be 3.

Any suggestions on where I might be going wrong?

Note:

error message is as follows:

```
req.session.user = rows[0]

TypeError: Cannot set property 'user' of undefined
```

Comment: Hi Bob, and welcome! The error happens because the request does not contain the session variable, so something might have gone wrong with the middleware. Can you confirm that the session initialization happens before the normal routing?:)

Comment: put app.use(cookieParser());
after app.use(session)

Comment: Im so stupid haha, simple mistake. I wasnt passing req when I was calling the login method